# Using wget to copy website with proper layout for offline browsing

Tags: backup, download, website, wget

This is the proper way to download a website with all the images and css files so that it has the same layout as the original but I don't know why the `-K --backup-converted` and `-E  --adjust-extension` options are necessary.

After the website is updated how do I update my backup/downloaded copy of the website? Just the same as for downloading?

```
wget -mpHkKEb -t 1 -e robots=off -U 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu;
Linux x86_64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0' http://www.example.com
```

- `–m (--mirror)` : turn on options suitable for mirroring (infinite recursive download and timestamps).
- `-p (--page-requisites)` : download all files that are necessary to properly display a given HTML page.  This includes such things as inlined images, sounds, and referenced stylesheets.
- `-H (--span-hosts)`: enable spanning across hosts when doing recursive retrieving.
- `–k (--convert-links)` : after the download, convert the links in document for local viewing.
- `-K (--backup-converted)` : when converting a file, back up the original version with a .orig suffix.  Affects the behavior of -N.
- `-E (--adjust-extension)` : add the proper extension to the end of the file.
- `-b (--background)` : go to background immediately after startup. If no output file is specified via the -o, output is redirected to wget-log.
- `-e (--execute)` : execute command (robots=off).
- `-t number (--tries=number)` : set number of tries to *number*.
- `-U (--user-agent)` :  identify as agent-string to the HTTP server. Some servers may ban you permanently for recursively download if you send the default User Agent.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/391622/download-a-whole-website-with-wget-or-other-including-all-its-downloadable-con

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
wget --mirror --convert-links --adjust-extension --page-requisites --no-parent http://example.org
```

ive used this in the past

from [Make Offline Mirror of a Site using `wget`](https://www.guyrutenberg.com/2014/05/02/make-offline-mirror-of-a-site-using-wget/):

> Explanation of the various flags:
>
> - `--mirror` – Makes (among other things) the download recursive.
> - `--convert-links` – Convert all the links (also to stuff like CSS stylesheets) to relative, so it will be suitable for offline viewing.
> - `--adjust-extension` – Adds suitable extensions to filenames (html or css) depending on their content-type.
> - `--page-requisites` – Download things like CSS style-sheets and images required to properly display the page offline.
> - `--no-parent` – When recursing do not ascend to the parent directory. It useful for restricting the download to only a portion of the site.