# Download whole website wget

Tags: linux, arch-linux, download, wget

I'm trying to download the entire contents of the site http://julesverne.ca/ using `wget`. I'm running the following command:

```
wget --wait 20 --limit-rate=20K --recursive --no-clobber --page-requisites --convert-links --domains julesverne.ca http://julesverne.ca/
```

The issue is: When I run the above command, `wget` only downloads `julesverne.ca/index.html`. Nothing more.

How can I get the whole site?

Comment: Do the site terms allow it to be scraped?

Comment: @music2myear I'm not exactly sure what you mean, but the site itself is a mirror of an old site that's gone down now, so I'm sure the owner doesn't mind.

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/970323/using-wget-to-copy-website-with-proper-layout-for-offline-browsing

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try

> ```
> wget -mpEk "url"
> ```
>
> Using `-m` (mirror) instead of `-r` is preferred as it intuitively
> downloads assets and you don't have to specify recursion depth, using
> mirror generally determines the correct depth to return a functioning
> site.
>
> The commands `-p -E -k` ensure that you're not downloading entire
> pages that might be linked to (e.g. Link to a Twitter profile results
> in you downloading Twitter code) while including all pre-requisite
> files (JavaScript, css, etc.) that the site needs. Proper site
> structure is preserved as well (instead of one big .html file with
> embedded scripts/stylesheet that can sometimes be the output.
>
> It's fast, I have never had to limit anything to get it to work and
> the resulting directory looks better than simply using the `-r` "url"
> arg and provides better insight into how the site was put together,
> especially if you're reverse-engineering for educational purposes.
>
> Note that if you're downloading a web-app or a site with lots of
> JavaScript that was compiled from TypeScript, you won't be able to get
> the TypeScript that was used initially, only what is compiled and sent
> to the browser. Take this into consideration if the site is very
> script heavy.

or use httrack

```
httrack --ext-depth=1 "url"
```